# Bash: store sql query in an array

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am running an sql query in bash to get file names and their schedule time. The files will then be run at the schedule time associated with it. The query out put is below. I need to capture the date and time and the file names and run the files at their specified time. How do I store both columns in separate arrays.

```
 file_name                | schedule_time
--------------------------+---------------------
 file 1                   | 2016-02-25 07:26:00
 file 2                   | 2016-02-26 07:37:00
 file 1                   | 2016-02-27 07:39:00
 file 3                   | 2016-02-27 12:00:00
 file 1                   | 2016-02-28 07:25:00
 file 2                   | 2016-02-29 02:15:00
 file 2                   | 2016-02-29 08:38:00
 file 1                   | 2016-02-29 12:00:00
```

Comment: Why not just keep the results in a file and read whatever entry from a cron job?

Comment: @anubhava I have never used cron before. How would I implement a cron job.

Comment: So you want in your shell program to have one array with all the file names, and one array with all the time stamps? The naive solution would be to just read the output line by line, split each line, and put the parts into the respective arrays (of course ignoring the first two lines). I just wonder what you want to do with the arrays afterwards. Are you sure, that a different data structure for processing your data wouldn't be better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why you need it, but here is a plain **bash** solution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sqldata="file_name                | schedule_time
 --------------------------+---------------------
  file 1                   | 2016-02-25 07:26:00
  file 2                   | 2016-02-26 07:37:00
  file 1                   | 2016-02-27 07:39:00
  file 3                   | 2016-02-27 12:00:00
  file 1                   | 2016-02-28 07:25:00
  file 2                   | 2016-02-29 02:15:00
  file 2                   | 2016-02-29 08:38:00
  file 1                   | 2016-02-29 12:00:00"

sqldata=$(echo "$sqldata" | tail -n +3) # skip first 3 lines

oldifs="$IFS"
IFS=$'\r\n'
lines=( $sqldata )
IFS="$oldifs"

files=()
dates=()
idx=0

for i in "${lines[@]}"
do
   files[idx]=$(echo $i  | sed -E 's/  +\|.*//')
   data[idx]=$(echo $i  | sed -E 's/ .*\|//')
   idx=$(($idx + 1))
done

echo files:
echo ${files[@]}
echo data:
echo ${data[@]}
```